# Can eclipse be used to fully replace ant?

Tags: eclipse, build

I don't want to build the files manually with command line,

is it possible for eclipse to do the equivalent for tomcat automatically?

Answer (score 1):

eclipse by default does compile your project automatically. Do you mean to have eclipse deploying to tomcat automatically?

If that is what you would like to do, [Eclipse WebT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)ools has support for deploying to servlet container. One example of how to do that is http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a build.xml file in your project root, you can right click on it in eclipse, select Run As -> Ant Build...

From there you can configure how it should run the script just as if you were using ant.

Answer (score 0):

Question title

> **Can eclipse be used to fully replace ant?**

Short answer: Do not compare apples with oranges.

> **Eclipse**  IDE (Building is one of its feature). [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)
>
> **Ant**      Build tool. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant)
>
> **Tomcat** Webserver. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat)